# Why is Asp.Net complaining that Ext JS3 is not passing a bool to action when checkbox is not checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs

In my Ext Js3 application I created a form with a checkbox with the following code:

```
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        fieldLabel: 'Is Automation Failure',
        inputValue: 'true',
        name: 'isAutomationFailure'
    }, {
```

When I check the checkbox it correctly sends `isAutomationFailure: true` to my Asp.NET MVC action, and life is good.  However, if I leave the checkbox unchecked, it gives:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'isAutomationFailure' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method

I understand that checkboxes do not send anything over if a checkbox isn't checked, but I was under the impression that a non-specified bool would default to false if not specified.  My action has the following signature:

```
    public virtual JsonResult SetTestRunFailureInfo(int runId, bool isAutomationFailure, int? tfsWorkitemId)
```

How can I get this to work (without having to resort to turning the parameter into a nullable type)?

Comment: Mvc gets around this by always rendering a hidden field with the same name and value set to false. This way they parse bools by seeing if they are truefalse or just false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `bool` to `bool?` and treat `null` as `false`. That's a "feature" of Ext JS.

```
isAutomationFailure = isAutomationFailure ?? false;
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer, as it seems like there is no other way to go about it except to use a nullable boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the inputValue property on a checkbox.  This explains how the value would be passed on a form submit: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp

Instead you should use the 'checked' property;

```
 }, {
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel: 'Is Automation Failure',
    checked: true,
    name: 'isAutomationFailure'
}, {
```

Comment: I don't understand why that would help?  First of all, I had to use `inputValue` because if I didn't the form would post `isAutomationFailure:on`, which would cause my C# boolean to be false.  Also, judging from the Ext JS 3 API docs, `checked` just influences the initial stage of the checkbox (which I don't care about since I am immediately loading it from my website upon form load)

Comment: You are right.  Apparently the nullable boolean is the way to go.